# CheckPoint VPN plugin returning "The server returned an invalid response" in Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, vpn

Our customer provides a Checkpoint-based VPN. My workstation runs Windows 8.1 Pro with the built-in VPN plugin for Checkpoint.

I have IP address of VPN and its credentials. I have followed the tutorial to configure the VPN in Windows but I got an error after authentication

The server returned an invalid response

Credentials are not domain credentials (plain username and password) and I am doubly sure they are correct, because if I willingly type them wrong I am requested them again.

Currently, I can't ask the customer IT to provide me assistance, as they may rethrow the ball to me saying they only support Windows 7 + official client.

Can I do something to diagnose or troubleshoot this kind of problem? Is there any patch that can be applied to the client in case of a common problem? My coworkers with Windows 7 have no problem connecting to that VPN.

[Add] Windows Event Log shows two related errors.
First, CheckPointVpnPluginApp.exe crashes on exception (code `c0000005` address `00007FFE9D7D0989`), then RasClient returns error 2250

Answer (score 0):

If we think this through... it looks like your local system is authenticating correctly but protocol wise there is something not working quite right.

It's almost as though the local system doesn't support the remote protocol (either disabled or just doesn't have a required component installed on your system. Common when vendors upgrade systems. Older protocols lose support).

There's a number of things we could try:
- an updated client? Ask Checkpoint. You never know when they might be releasing a new client.
- a different client. As long as the protocol in question is supported then you should be able to acheive connectivity.
- a virtual machine on your Windows 8 machine running Windows 7 with the proper client.
- obviously, downgrading your machine to Windows 7.
- a tunnel setup. So you setup a different machine which basically has the client setup to connect via VPN. However, you can connect to this machine via a different protocol such as RDP or VNC.

If you really want to troubleshoot this protocol issue. Have Wireshark running on a Win 7 system and on your Win 8.1 system. Take note of when exactly the remote system decides to declare the session invalid. This will give you an idea of what is missing/wrong (may also be helpful in your discussion with CheckPoint themselves).

https://www.wireshark.org/

https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk96006

Comment: I expect the Win7 VM to work, this is a viable solution but I'd have preferred it to work on my Windows 8 natively (or the error message to be more specific). Maybe I'll try Wireshark